# How to theme the edit page of a form and retrieve $form variable from the hook_form_alter into the template for theming purposes?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have a content type A
How can I add custom theme to **edit** page of that content type A in drupal 7 only for specific role ?
In my module,

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
if (form_id == 'content_type_a') {
global $user;

if (in_array('rad',$user->roles)) {
$form['#theme'][] = 'custom_content_type_a_node_form';
}
}
}
```

In my template.php file I have the following code

```
function hook_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom_content_type_a_node_form' => array(
      'variables' => array('form' => NULL),
    );
  );
}

function THEMENAME_custom_content_type_a_node_form($form) {
// When I check here for $form I get an empty value 
// I want to get the $form value derived from the form_alter function's $form //variable . How can I achieve it?




}
```

How can I retrieve the $form value from the hook_form_alter's $form variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function hook_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom_content_type_a_node_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    );
  );
}

function THEMENAME_custom_content_type_a_node_form($variables) {
  dpm($variables);
}
```

Comment: but will it give me $form from hook_form_alter ?

Comment: the above code using 'render element' does not work . The problem which occurs is th node edit page does not load and keeps on loading

Comment: @harshal I am testing this..

Comment: @harshal This is correct - you'll find the render element (the form) in `$variables['form']`

Comment: but will I get the $form from the hook_form_alter()?anyways i will try it again

Comment: You'll get the form that you attached the theme function to, so yes

Comment: @harshal I figured out.. You need to call #theme like this: `array_unshift($form['#theme'], 'custom_content_type_a_node_form')`

Comment: ok i will try this and let u know if it works

Comment: @xurshid29 Are you sure about that? `$form['#theme']` is [supposed to be a string](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#theme), not an array.

Comment: @Clive In my case `$form['#theme']` is an array and it holds all theme functions (exposed_form theme functions). I needed to put my theme function at the beginning of that array to call it first, after that  views call other functions..

Comment: while trying above array_unshift($form['#theme'], 'custom_content_type_a_node_form') I checked in dpm for $variables and it gave me memory exhausted error

Comment: @harshal At first you need to debug your form (which you are altering) and find `#theme` attribute if it exist..

Comment: yes $form['#theme'] with the function custom_content_type_a_node_form exists i have checked that but the problem is the $variables

Comment: @harshal your theme function is the last element of that array?

Comment: ok on refreshing the page again I got the $variables as $form variable from hook_form_alter()  thanks for the help

Comment: [#theme] => Array
                (
             [0] => custom_trans_node_form
                    [1] => trans_node_form
             [2] => node_form
                )

Comment: this is the array for ['#theme'] in the $form['#theme'] i got and its working anyways

Comment: @harshal I am glad to help you..